# Browserify: using external libraries from within bundle

Tags: javascript, bundle, external, browserify

Our team develops browser side `javascript` app. We use `angularjs` as framework and some helper libraries in global namespace. For example: `underscore`.

We carried out a large piece of code (input/output data tranformation) into a standalone library for unit testing reasons.

Now i try to use `browserify` with this library. The question is about what the best way to exclude from bundle shared (with main app) dependences (underscore for example).
I tried 2:

1. Using --external. I have to create bundle from underscore and use it for all code stuff in app. If i understood right this way seems inconvenient.
2. Using `browser` property in package.json to replace underscore with stub:

   module.exports = _;

I believe that there is more clean approach, but where is it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `--external` or something like that. Just include the library like this:

```
<script src="external/lib.js"></script>
```

then you can use it within your bundle (**without** `require`).

BUT: In my opinion you shouldn't mix global libs with `browserify`. All benefits of `browserify` will decrease drastically this way.

Contras:

- more than one file to include
- worse readability cause fewer `require` statements

RECOMMEND:

create one bundle with all external libs and install them as npm modules.

```
npm install --save angular
npm install --save lodash
```

create external bundle:

```
browserify -r angular -r lodash > external/libs.js
```

you only have to bundle it once because they should never change. then create main app bundle without external modules:

```
browserify --no-bundle-external app.js > bundle.js
```

then include these two bundles to your page:

```
<script src="external/libs.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Problem is that i have to use `require('./external/lib')` for testing purpose in node environment.

Comment: I don't know whether one can use angular with commonjs modules... It has its own approach for modules management. For this reason i would like to keep the rest of app as is.

Comment: ok. NOTE: i have often heard about problems when using `browserify` with `commonjs` modules. Sry, but i cannot help with that.

Comment: Do we have to remove require from all files then when using external libs?

Comment: Yes. When you include the libraray directly in your html file (and don't use something like browserify to bundle/scope your code) you have the remove the hole require statement, `var lib = require("external/lib.js");`. The library should be accessible in the global space. You just have to use it.